# Event trigger based on historical data

Tags: r

Here's the data:

```
df <- data.table(time = rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-10"), 1), 2),
                 sensor = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
                 event = 0)
df$event[c(3,8,11,12)] <- 1

          time sensor event
 1: 2016-01-01      A     0
 2: 2016-01-02      A     0
 3: 2016-01-03      A     1
 4: 2016-01-04      A     0
 5: 2016-01-05      A     0
 6: 2016-01-06      A     0
 7: 2016-01-07      A     0
 8: 2016-01-08      A     1
 9: 2016-01-09      A     0
10: 2016-01-10      A     0
11: 2016-01-01      B     1
12: 2016-01-02      B     1
13: 2016-01-03      B     0
14: 2016-01-04      B     0
15: 2016-01-05      B     0
16: 2016-01-06      B     0
17: 2016-01-07      B     0
18: 2016-01-08      B     0
19: 2016-01-09      B     0
20: 2016-01-10      B     0
```

Idea is that there's a certain event that can trigger a sensor. Data is logged at fixed intervals. After event there's a need to perform a certain action for next three periods. What I'd like to see in data is to create another column that is 1 when event == 1 in any given period and for next 3 periods and 0 otherwise. Like this:

```
> df
          time sensor event result
 1: 2016-01-01      A     0      0
 2: 2016-01-02      A     0      0
 3: 2016-01-03      A     1      1
 4: 2016-01-04      A     0      1
 5: 2016-01-05      A     0      1
 6: 2016-01-06      A     0      1
 7: 2016-01-07      A     0      0
 8: 2016-01-08      A     1      1
 9: 2016-01-09      A     0      1
10: 2016-01-10      A     0      1
11: 2016-01-01      B     1      1
12: 2016-01-02      B     1      1
13: 2016-01-03      B     0      1
14: 2016-01-04      B     0      1
15: 2016-01-05      B     0      1
16: 2016-01-06      B     0      0
17: 2016-01-07      B     0      0
18: 2016-01-08      B     0      0
19: 2016-01-09      B     0      0
20: 2016-01-10      B     0      0
```

One way to do it is to create a temp column with end period for all event == 1. Such as:

```
df[,temp:=ifelse(event == 1, time + 3, NA)][,temp:=as.Date(temp, origin)]
```

And then loop through all valid date pairs and set result column to 1 in all time intervals. But loop is generally a bad idea when you have large quantity of sensors and observations.

So maybe there's a better way to do this without nested loop for every sensor type and every valid date pair?

And a question that probably deserves a separate post: can similar triggers/rules be implemented straight onto SQL database?

**Update:**

Here's my solution to the problem. I truly think that I'm over-complicating this and losing a lot of efficiency in the process:

```
df[,temp:=ifelse(event == 1, time + 3, NA)][,temp:=as.Date(temp, origin)]

dateFun <- function(x){
  c(x[1], seq.Date(as.Date(x[2]), as.Date(x[3]), 1))
}

x <- data.table(t(apply(df[!is.na(temp),.SD,by = sensor,.SDcols = c("time","temp")], 1, function(x) dateFun(x))))
x <- x[,t(.SD),by=sensor][,V1:=as.Date(as.numeric(V1), origin)]

df[,result:=ifelse(paste(sensor, time) %in% paste(x$sensor, x$V1), 1, 0)][,temp:=NULL]
```

Idea is that I create a temporary column for all "event == 1" to show a supposed end period at T+3. Then I create a new data frame with all seq.Date() to store all dates that should be set as "1" in result column. Then I match the value pairs of time + sensor.

Any better ideas? Keep in mind that I have ~1mil of sensors and have to keep track of results for ~100 periods. And I have ~500 observations. Therefore this intermediate data.frame with all dates for all events is simply not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to split the data by sensor first, then something like this should work

```
tmp <- lapply(which(df$event),"+", 0:3)
df$result <- 0
df$result[unique(unlist(tmp))] <- 1
```

You would need to force values in tmp to be no larger than nrow(df)

Comment: Sensors were just a convenient way to convey the idea. I have ~1 million of "sensors". And split by sensors seems to be the first layer of loop, lapply is the second layer of loop. I don't really think this will be very efficient (I will try though). I should probably try an `.SD` on `data.table` by sensor and then `apply` a function... and benchmark different approaches. But `.SD` is known for not scaling very well.